# chrome onStartup event only firing sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm coding a chrome extension which needs to keep track of when chrome starts up after crashing or shutdown. I am using a the onStartup event in the top level of a service worker:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
    console.log("started up");
})
```

My problem is that it only sometimes fires and I don't know why. I have been testing it by killing chrome in the task manager then starting it again and checking the console to see if it has logged. It logs about half the time.

What am I missing? Am I using the wrong event? Does killing it in the task manager not do quite what I think it does? Is there a better way to simulate crashes?

I'm pretty new to programming, so thank you for responding if this turns out to just be a silly question!

Comment: This event fires one time per user profile, so it won't fire after restarting the extension.